# How to disable Coveo search on CM without impacting Coveo command center in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore-client, coveo

I am trying to disable coveo search on CM using the setting

`<add key="coveo:define" value="Disabled" />`

But it also stops Coveo command center.

Is there a way if I can disable only coveo search in CM environment without impacting command center?

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling the Coveo configs. All you have to do is remove (make sure you keep a copy of them) or change the extension of all the configuration files under:

- \App_Config\Include\Coveo
- \App_Config\Include\ExperienceAnalyticsCoveo (if it applies)
- \App_Config\Include\ExperienceProfileCoveo (if it applies)

Comment: I guess ,in Sitecore 9 we do not  have to make so many changes. Only <add key="coveo:define" value="Disabled" /> is sufficient but the issue is  it also disables command center which I do not want.  https://hls-consulting.com/2018/06/21/sitecore-9-and-coveo-how-to-disable-coveo-in-5-seconds/